# Add second root filesystem

Tags: linux

Is it possible to add a "fallback" file system on Linux? So if e.g. /usr/lib/gimp isn't found, it'll search a secondary mount point?

I have a customized not-actually-chrootable chroot on an SD card with extracted Debian packages. What I want to do is be able to run e.g. gimp and have it use the software on the SD card without having to install a full system and chrooting into it.

Comment: This is what your PATH is for.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton That only works for *programs*. Even if you also specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, e.g. /usr/share doesn't fall back.